# Overhead on an SQL insert significant?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, insert

I have a python script which hits dozens of API endpoints every 10s to write climate data to a database. Lets say on average I insert 1,500 rows every 10 seconds, from 10 different threads.

I am thinking of making a batch system whereby the insert queries aren't written to the db as they come in, but added to a waiting list and this list is inserted in batch when it reaches a certain size, and the list of course emptied.

1. Is this justified due to the overhead with frequently writing small numbers of rows to the db?
2. If so, would a list be wise? I am worried about if my program terminates unexpectedly, perhaps a form of serialized data would be better?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

150 inserts per second *can* be a load on a database and can affect performance.  There are pros and cons to changing the approach that you have.  Here are some things to consider:

- Databases implement ACID, so inserts are secure.  This is harder to achieve with buffering schemes.
- How important is up-to-date information for queries?
- What is the query load?
- `insert` is pretty simple.  Alternative mechanisms may require re-inventing the wheel.
- Do you have other requirements on the inserts, such as ensuring they are in particular order?

No doubt, there are other considerations.

Here are some possible alternative approaches:

- If recent data is not a concern, snapshot the database for querying purposes -- say once per day or once per hour.
- Batch inserts in the application threads.  A single insert can insert multiple rows.
- Invest in larger hardware.  An insert load that slows down a single processor may have little effect on a a larger machine.
- Invest in better hardware.  More memory and faster disk (particularly solid state) and have a big impact.

No doubt, there are other approaches as well.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @GordonLinoff. Forgive me but I don't understand how a buffering scheme could affect ACID. I'm still writing the queries in Postgres. Isn't the RDBMS going to prevent anything like that happening?

Comment: @JSStuball . . . ACID only applies to the work the database is doing.  If you have a buffering scheme outside the database, then you need to ensure integrity.